# VUE: data is fetched but not shown with vueD3tree

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to **Vue** and VueD3tree. I’m trying to show a tree using vued3tree library with data fetched from API. When I tried to use the same data as static, the tree is shown perfectly. However, in case of fetching data, the “console.log” in **created()** function prints the data as JSON string which means the data is fetched successfully. But instead of showing it in the tree, only a small circle representing the tree’s root is shown, only that circle, nothing else. I also got the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
> at u (index.js:1)
> at SVGGElement. (index.js:2)
> at SVGGElement. (attr.js:29)
> at sn.Ue [as each] (each.js:5)
> at sn.tt [as attr] (attr.js:53)
> at o.updateGraph (index.js:2)
> at o. (index.js:2)
> at Array. (vue.runtime.esm.js:1980)
> at ft (vue.runtime.esm.js:1906)

Here is my code if you could have a look, in **ProductTree.vue** file:

```
<template > <div id="tree"> <div>  <div > 
<tree :data="tree"   node-text="title"  layoutType="horizontal"
type="tree"  Duration="0"  style="width:600px; height:600px" ></tree>
</div> </div> </template>

import { tree } from "vued3tree";
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "ProductTree",
  components: {
       tree,
  },
  data() {    
      return {     
             tree:{}
    };},
async created(){
      let response = await Service.getProducts();
      this.tree=this.prepareData(response.data.data);
      console.log(this.tree);
},
methods: {
      prepareData(data){
       ...
       return data;
       },
      });
```

In **Products.vue**, I have:

```
<div> <ProductTree/> </div>
```

I think the problem is not in vued3tree library or the data itself but it is in binding the data, I’m new to **Vue** and couldn’t figure out how to do it. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You have naming conflict between component and data. I would try changing `tree` in data to `treeData` or something other than the one declared in the component.

Comment: @HeriHeheSetiawan Thanks, I tried but nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by adding v-if=“dataLoaded” on the tree component and set the dataLoaded property to true loading the data. Also, I had to use json object instead of json string.